# Why does my record have all nil fields after being saved?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js, ember-data, jsonapi-rails

I am making an ember and rails app.

I am trying to do a post request to http://localhost:3000/candidates

My request is getting a 200 and is creating a record but everything is nil:
Why is this?

```
#<Candidate id: 15, name: nil, email: nil, created_at: "2018-08-23 22:28:07", updated_at: "2018-08-23 22:28:07">
```

here is my controller code:

```
class CandidatesController < ApplicationController
  # POST /candidates
  # def create
  #   @candidate = Candidate.create!(candidate_params)
  #   json_response(@candidate, :created)
  # end

  def create
    puts "create"
    puts params
    puts candidate_params
    candidate = Candidate.create!(candidate_params)

    if candidate.save
      render jsonapi: candidate
    else
      render jsonapi_errors: candidate.errors
    end
  end

  private

  def candidate_params
    # whitelist params
    params.permit(:name, :email)
  end
end
```

and here is my ember code:

```
import Ember from "ember";

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model() {
    // return this.get("store").findAll("candidate");
  },
  actions: {
    createCandidate() {
      console.log("create candidate");
      let candidate = this.get("store").createRecord("candidate", {
        id: 1,
        name: "Katie",
        email: "katie@gmail.com"
      });
      candidate.save();
    }
  }
});
```

I am also getting this error in my js console:
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input

I am using the 'jsonapi-rails' gem

Here are the server logs and screen shot of network tab:

[NetworkScreenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJMld.png)

```
Started POST "/candidates" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-08-29 14:07:12 +0100
Processing by CandidatesController#create as application/vnd.api+json
create
{"controller"=>"candidates", "action"=>"create"}
{}
   (2.7ms)  begin transaction
  ↳ app/controllers/candidates_controller.rb:12
  Candidate Create (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "candidates" ("created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?)  [["created_at", "2018-08-29 13:07:12.984174"], ["updated_at", "2018-08-29 13:07:12.984174"]]
  ↳ app/controllers/candidates_controller.rb:12
   (1.3ms)  commit transaction
  ↳ app/controllers/candidates_controller.rb:12
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  ↳ app/controllers/candidates_controller.rb:14
   (0.0ms)  commit transaction
  ↳ app/controllers/candidates_controller.rb:14
Completed 200 OK in 9ms (Views: 0.1ms | ActiveRecord: 4.5ms)
```

This is my adapter:

```
import DS from "ember-data";

export default DS.JSONAPIAdapter.extend({
  host: "http://localhost:3000",
  dataType: "json"
});
```

I am not using any serializer in the frontend. should I be?
Yes I am expecting jsonapi data.

Comment: What do your params look like?

Comment: Here are my params:
{"controller"=>"candidates", "action"=>"create"}

Comment: Do you have any model data in your params?

Comment: Your JS code is not sending params(name, email etc) to the rails app. Also you don't have to pass id as it is automatically created by rails.

Comment: First you need to have some [model validations](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html) in place, so that you don't end up with a database full of null values.

Comment: Can you show the server logs for the request?

Comment: The problem seems to be in `ember` code, **name** and **email** are not there in params.

Comment: can you shrare a snippet from the network log in chrome? showing the headers / parameters along with the request?

does your Candidate model in ember-data define name and email?

Comment: A normal Ruby on Rails form nests the resource params inside the resource namespace. This means `params.permit(:name, :email)` should be `params.require(:candidate).permit(:name, :email)`. Posting the incoming params from the server log might help.

Comment: @Kato can you share your ember-data model for this? what adapter / serializer are you using on the frontend? Are you expecting jsonapi formatted json documents? or something else?

Comment: @NullVoxPopuli I have added that info to the question. thanks

Comment: can you add the model, too? thaaaaaanks :)

Comment: oh hey, actually, you have a network screenshot, which is a tooon of information. Things look good on the frontend side!

Comment: so, I don't know enough about jsonapi-rails to debug this. :(
(i'm more ember now a days).
is there anyway you can use `binding.pry` at the top of your controller action and inspect the `params` object? see what's in there?

Comment: I got it working! @NullVoxPopuli thanks for your help!!

Comment: yay!!! what was the issue?

Comment: I made a change in my controller, I had to do params.require(:_jsonapi).require(:data).require(:attributes) and I also forgot to add a serializer in the frontend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define a model into your ember app :
https://guides.emberjs.com/release/models/#toc_models

Moreover, if you are using jsonapi specs, you should set [related adapter](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/models/customizing-adapters/)

```
// app/adapters/application.js
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.JSONAPIAdapter.extend({});
```

[and serializer](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/models/customizing-serializers/)

```
// app/serializers/application.js
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.JSONAPISerializer.extend({});
```

Comment: thanks! It's working now, I forgot to add a serializer!